# Meteor js mongodb SUM collection documents is incomplete

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a problem which I do not know where to start. I have a button that calculates total amount from all matching documents in a collection. ie: certain month, year and branch calculations. So far, when I click it first time it gives me "y" amount, second time returns "x" amount.

What I suppose is that collection documents is incomplete when first time.

How may I solve this? Please excuse me if this has already been answered, I have looked around unsuccessfully.

When button is clicked, in template events executes:

```
'click #calculate': function(event,instance){
   var _transactions = instance.Transactions().fetch();
   var capital = _transactions.reduce(function(sum, row){
      return row.is_accountable ? sum + row.transaction_amount : sum + 0;
   }, 0);
   instance.capital.set(capital);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Blaze you might consider making this computation a helper instead of an event handler. That way (a) the user doesn't need to click to get the sum, (b) the total will always be up-to-date even if the data changes reactively.

```
Template.myTemplate.helper({
  sum(){
    s = 0;
    Transactions.find().map((doc)={
      s += doc.is_accountable ? doc.transaction_amount : 0;
    });
    return s;
  }
});
```